# Confluence atlassian change event listener

Tags: confluence

I am planning to register an event listener, to listen for any content change happens on the Confluence wiki for my organization as part of a project and take curtain actions like re indexing the data to elastic search. I have found sample example to write a listener from - https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/event-listener-module/writing-an-event-listener-plugin-module

But I am not sure how to integrate this solution with existing Confluence service so that I start getting events? Any working example share or leads towards this will be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Confluence Server, you'll need to [install the Atlassian SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/install-the-atlassian-sdk-on-a-linux-or-mac-system) on your development machine and create a [Confluence add-on](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins).

Having done all that, you should have a skeleton Confluence add-on.

Next, you'll need to add an event listener `component` and an `eventPublisher` `component-import` to your `atlassian-plugin.xml` file like so:

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
    </plugin-info>

    <component 
        key="scroll-versions-event-listener" 
        class="me.davidsimpson.confluence.addons.example.listener.ScrollVersionsPublishEventListener" 
        name="Scroll Versions Publish Event Listener" 
        >
    </component>

    <component-import key="eventPublisher" interface="com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher" />

</atlassian-plugin>
```

Next, you'll need to create the class file for the event listener.  Here's a starting point:

```
package me.davidsimpson.confluence.addons.example.listener;

import com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;

public class ScrollVersionsPublishEventListener implements DisposableBean
{
    protected final EventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public ScrollVersionsPublishEventListener(EventPublisher eventPublisher)
    {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        eventPublisher.register(this);
    }

    /**
     * Unregister the listener if the plugin is uninstalled or disabled.
     */
    public void destroy() throws Exception
    {
        eventPublisher.unregister(this);
    }

    @com.atlassian.event.api.EventListener
    public void onVersionPublishEvent(Object event) {

        String eventName = event.getClass().getCanonicalName(); // will work for other people's events, not just Atlassian's

        // Spit out all events - just to prove the point
        System.out.println(" ++ an event happened: " + eventName);

        if (eventName.equals("com.k15t.scroll.platform.event.space.VersionPublishEvent")) {
            System.out.println(" ++++ Found the right event ");

            // Do your stuff here...
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in this example, all events are printed to the console, but we're checking for a specific non-standard event in this example.

Change `if (eventName.equals(...))` to the event you are interested in and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to re-render a page if an specific event occures ?

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean. Do you mean some kind of client-side javascript event? Or a server-side Confluence event?

Normal Confluence events will have no concept of who might have a page open at trigger time.